# How to handle long email address with regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regex for the email validation:

```
private const string ValidEmailRegexPattern = @"^(?:[^@\s\\(),:;<>[\]""]+|(?:(?:^|\.)""(?:[^\r\\"";]|(?:\\[\\""]))*"")+)+(?<=^.{1,64})@[^\s~!@#$%^&*()=+_{}\|;,`'""?<>]{1,256}$";

public static bool IsValidEmail(string email)
{
     return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email) && ValidEmailRegex.IsMatch(email);
}
```

But it is froze when input is valid email, but with maximum valid length (254 symbols) like this:

`"123...@gmail.com"` - `254` symbols, including `244` numbers and `@gmail.com`.

How to change my regex? I want that my program can handle that type of email address.

Comment: What do you mean by 'it is froze'?

Comment: @PraveenPaulose The program is not responding

Comment: Use a different regular expression (google it), or even better just [don’t validate email addresses with regexes at all](http://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/).

Comment: O my god. That is bizarre regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [MailAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress.aspx) class to validate the email instead of validating it using the regex.

```
MailAddress m = new MailAddress(email);
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01escwtf.aspx)

> Instead of using a regular expression to validate an email address,
>   you can use the **System.Net.Mail.MailAddress** class. To determine
>   whether an email address is valid, pass the email address to the
>   MailAddress.MailAddress(String) class constructor.

Comment: You can vote to close as duplicate instead of duplicating answers.

Comment: @CodeCaster:- Will take care in future. Didn't checked for duplicates at that time!

Comment: @CodeCaster, that is not prohibited.

Comment: @Giorgi no it is not and I am not saying it is, but you'd expect better from an 80K rep user. That's all. This answer does not explain _why_ you should use this approach, and it does not explain that the only valid form of email validation is to send an email to the provided address, but hey, give him four upvotes. Or five.

Comment: @RahulTripathi Thank you for support!

Comment: MailAddress does not handle 255 symbols(invalid email). So using this class its not a solution